# ¿SDK PHP de Facebook requiere SSL?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Con js puedo obtener toda la info pero e leído por internet que algunos tiene  problemas algunos con php dicen que es por el hosting y otros por que requiere tener un certificado SSL alguno sabe si es así o no? por que en la documentación no e encontrado nada con respecto a esto.

Comment: No, no lo requiere. Si es verdad que algunos navegadores piden SSL para algunas funciones por ejemplo Google Chrome te impide acceder a la ubicación del usuario sin un certificado SSL valido